# Connection timeout on Cassandra cluster using Phantom

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm playing a bit with phantom-dsl and I successfully achieved a read/write operation on a cluster using `CassandraTable` class.

However, if the while cluster is down or if configuration is wrong, I would like fail fast: stop my CLI with a specific timeout and exit the program, actually *before* trying to write something.

What could be a good way to achieve this? I've tried this so far:

```
object Config {
  val keySpace = KeySpace("myreallyfirstks")
  val contactPoint: KeySpaceBuilder = ContactPoint(host = "localhost", port = ContactPoint.DefaultPorts.live)
  val keySpaceDefinition: KeySpaceDef = contactPoint.keySpace(keySpace.name)

  lazy val session: Session = keySpaceDefinition.provider.getSession(keySpace.name)

  trait StandardConnector extends keySpaceDefinition.Connector
}
```

and then

```
  val test = Try(Config.session.executeAsync("select * from  system.schema_columns limit 1;").get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))

  Try(test) match {
    case Success(_) => println("Someone is alive")
    case Failure(ex) => println(s"The cluster is down")
  }
```

however this returns me success even if I'm pointing to an address where C* is not installed.

Using `Session`skips totally phantom going directly to the Java driver, however there may be something in phantom that I do not know and it's already done for this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, except you are just meant to mix `keySpaceDefinition.Connector` wherever appropriate, not access any of the internal stuff. That's the first one.

The idea is to use a `DatabaseImpl` and then pass your `KeySpaceDef` as a constructor argument to that:

```
class Database(val space: KeySpaceDef) extends DatabaseImpl(space) {
  object users extends Users with space.Connector
  ..
}
```

And then you can create an object from this or use a provider trait to inject one the Scala way(no Google Guice or whatever), as the blog post demonstrates.

Then in a controller:

```
trait Controller {
  def database: Database

 def findUser(email: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
   // For this you might need to mix in a connector into the Controller
   // itself, since all query methods needs the implicit session
   // and keySpace definition.
   database.users.select.where(_.email eqs email).one()
 }
}
```

Next, to catch initialisation problems in due time all you need is a catch block around the initialisation of the session.